# How to reset password of a CVS user?

Tags: cvs

I have no knowledge of CVS administration. It's installed in my server and unfortunately the password of my user is not working. I was using this user to commit/checkout code from Eclipse. I don't have the `root` access of this server.

Is there any way that I can reset the password of my CVS user?

Following screenshot is showing CVS settings of an eclipse project. 
[image]

Following is CVS Repository view

[image]

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it appears that CVS is setup to use `ssh` to connect to the server running the CVS repository.

If you can use an *ssh client* to login to that server, (since you don't know the password, this would have to be via a *previously established ssh key*), then you could reset your password there (with the `passwd` command most likely).  Otherwise, you're going to need the assistance of an admin on the server.

Comment: I can see my username directory in `/home/`. So if I get reset the password of user by sys admin, the same can be used for login to CVS?

Comment: Yes, it appears to me that is how your system is setup. Your sys admin should know what to do in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Wel this question is old but in case of...

There may be several ways to login into "CVS" server.
The most common way to setup a user is adding it to the repository CVSROOT/passwd file, through the use of the htpassword for generating the password footprint.

It means that you must have a RW access on the server filesystem ( at least the CSVROOT directory).